# React DND, connectDragSource not a function error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dnd

I'm trying to to follow along in the React DND Chess tutorial (simple enough), but I've seem to hit a snag with a piece of my code. I am getting a error stating that connectDragSource is not a function, when I've declared it as such as seen in my code below. I've tried troubleshooting it for the past day, and have ran out of leads. If it helps, I'm using the React-Redux-Universal  boiler, but I doubt that is causing any issues via my routes and children being rendered.

Component Code:

```
 import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { DragSource } from 'react-dnd';
import { ItemTypes } from './Constants.js';

require('./box1.css');


const pieceSource = {
    beginDrag(props){
        return {};
    }
};

function collect(connect, monitor) {
  return {
    connectDragSource: connect.DragSource(),
    isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
  }
};


export default class Student extends Component{

  render() {
    const { connectDragSource, isDragging } = this.props;
      return connectDragSource(
        <div style={{
          opacity: isDragging ? 0.5 : 1,
          fontSize: 25,
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          cursor: 'move'
        }}>
          ♘ !
        </div>
    );
  }
}

Student.PropTypes = {
  connectDragSource: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isDragging: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};



DragSource(ItemTypes.STUDENT, pieceSource, collect)(Student);
```

Home Component Code:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import Header from '../../components/Header/header';
import Footer from '../../components/Footer/footer';
import Student from '../../components/box1/box1';
import { DragDropContext } from 'react-dnd';
import HTML5Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';
require('./home.css');


 class Home extends Component{
  render() {

    return (



        <div id="main">

              Hello World  
               <Student />



          </div>

    );
  }
}

export default DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(Home);
```

App Code:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
require('./app.css');

export default React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="app">
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: This: `connectDragSource: connect.DragSource(),` sets the "connectDragSource" property to the value returned by calling `connect.DragSource()` - is that really what you want? Does that function return another function?

Comment: Yes, that is what the intended use is for, since it is a Higher Order function. It's just like what is listed on the React DND tutorial @Pointy

Comment: Well, if you're getting that error, maybe something isn't working the way you think it should. You could add some code to log the value in that "collect" function before it returns the object.

Comment: That is a really smart idea, let me go try that. Thanks @Pointy

Comment: @Pointy I just thought about this, but the 'collect' function is actually not being called as of yet; it only get's called once DND is monitoring/checking for updated values (and since the module can never be built, it's actually never being executed). The problem I noticed, lies when I try to wrap the JSX return div in as my connectDragSource function (in the component code), that's what's breaking it, but I have no clue why. And I'm explicitly declaring it a function w/ PropTypes.funct.isRequired. So that makes it even more confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed my issue, by switching everything over from ES6 to ES5 Syntax. Really weird, but it worked, see code below:

```
var React = require('react');
var PropTypes = React.PropTypes;
var ItemTypes = require('./Constants').ItemTypes;
var DragSource = require('react-dnd').DragSource;

var knightSource = {
  beginDrag: function (props) {
    return {};
  }
};

function collect(connect, monitor) {
  return {
    connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
    isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
  }
}

var Knight = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    connectDragSource: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    isDragging: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
  },

  render: function () {
    var connectDragSource = this.props.connectDragSource;
    var isDragging = this.props.isDragging;

    return connectDragSource(
      <div style={{
        opacity: isDragging ? 0.5 : 1,
        fontSize: 25,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        cursor: 'move'
      }}>
        ♘
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = DragSource(ItemTypes.KNIGHT, knightSource, collect)(Knight);
```